# Unity shiny shader overlay 2D sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, sprite

I have a Unity shader to shiny for 2D sprite:

```html
//Kaan Yamanyar,Levent Seckin
Shader "Sprites/ShinyDefault"
{
 Properties
 {
  [PerRendererData] _MainTex("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
 _Color("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
  _ShineLocation("ShineLocation", Range(0,1)) = 0
  _ShineWidth("ShineWidth", Range(0,1)) = 0
  [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
 }

  SubShader
 {
  Tags
 {
  "Queue" = "Transparent"
  "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
  "RenderType" = "Transparent"
  "PreviewType" = "Plane"
  "CanUseSpriteAtlas" = "False"
 }

  Cull Off
  Lighting Off
  ZWrite Off
  Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

  Pass
 {
  CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag
#pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON
#include "UnityCG.cginc"

  struct appdata_t
 {
  float4 vertex   : POSITION;
  float4 color    : COLOR;
  float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
 };

 struct v2f
 {
  float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
  fixed4 color : COLOR;
  float2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
 };

 fixed4 _Color;

 v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
 {
  v2f OUT;
  OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
  OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
  OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
#ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
  OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap(OUT.vertex);
#endif

  return OUT;
 }

 sampler2D _MainTex;
 sampler2D _AlphaTex;
 float _AlphaSplitEnabled;
 float _ShineLocation;
 float _ShineWidth;

 fixed4 SampleSpriteTexture(float2 uv)
 {
  fixed4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, uv);

#if UNITY_TEXTURE_ALPHASPLIT_ALLOWED
  if (_AlphaSplitEnabled)
   color.a = tex2D(_AlphaTex, uv).r;
#endif //UNITY_TEXTURE_ALPHASPLIT_ALLOWED




  float lowLevel = _ShineLocation - _ShineWidth;
  float highLevel = _ShineLocation + _ShineWidth;
  float currentDistanceProjection = (uv.x + uv.y) / 2;
  if (currentDistanceProjection > lowLevel && currentDistanceProjection < highLevel) {
   float whitePower = 1 - (abs(currentDistanceProjection - _ShineLocation) / _ShineWidth);
   color.rgb += color.a * whitePower;
  }

  return color;
 }

 fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
 {
  fixed4 c = SampleSpriteTexture(IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
 c.rgb *= c.a;

 return c;
 }
  ENDCG
 }
 }
}
```

But with this code the pixels of 2D sprite are behind this shiny shader. Now I want to show only this shader overlay sprite and all pixels in sprite are not showing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `SortingLayer` or `OrderInLayer` for the renderer which is using the shader.

for example, go to Edit -> project settings -> tags and layers and define a layer named overlay layer and place it after the layer used by sprites and then:

```
[shaderedObject].GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingLayerName = "overlay layer";
```